# HTML link anchor inside ActionScript 3?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, anchor

is there any way to click on a flash button ni as3 and take me to certain part of one html page like the html normal # anchor links work?

i tried with

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("cruceros_europa.html#center"), "_self");
```

but it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Will it open to the `cruceros_europa.html` page without the anchor?

Comment: it does open it but from the top

Comment: And if you type `yoursite.com/cruceros_europa.html#center` directly in a browser's address bar will it go to the anchor or does it stay at the top? I'm with Marty, you should verify that your anchor on your html is set up right.

Comment: Yes it works fine, i even made a test simple html with the links to verify that i set up them well, but in the flash menu doesnt work always open it from the top, and even the address bar looks like a normal link without the anchor #x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.. Are you sure you've set up your anchor right?

Try this, for example:

```
navigateToURL(
    new URLRequest("http://projectavian.com/blog/#footer")
);
```